# In Illustrator is it possible to take apart a Smart Object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, smartobject

In IllustratorCC is it possible to take apart a Smart Object? I had a client send me a logo from another artist to update (former artist is no longer available to answer). I need to take apart the Smart Object to see exactly how the comprising elements were made so as to update.

Comment: Smart Objects don't exist in in Illustrator. They are a Photoshop thing. In Illustrator you might have a group, but not a "Smart Object".

Answer (score -1):

It's possible, but it depends on how the object was created in the first place. Here are the basic steps:

1. Select the Smart Object from the Layers panel
2. Double-click the Smart Objects thumbnail in the Layers panel.
3. Make edits to the source content file, then choose File > Save.

[More details here](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html#edit_the_content_of_a_smart_object).

Comment: My assumption was that the smart object was found in a PSD, and the OP was asking how to "break apart" (edit) that smart object in Illustrator.